# Glass Cast issues after upgrading from Sitecore 7.2 to 8.2

Tags: mvc, upgrade, glass-mapper

So, I upgraded a Sitecore solution from 7.2 to 8.2. All works well, except for the site. I keep on getting the error in my views like the one below:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type  'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Web.ViewModels.XXXViewModel'.

I did update all my Glass Cast references to `sitecoreService.Cast<>()`. But still no luck. Did anyone run into this issue?

We are using Glass Mapper (Version 4.2.1.188).

Comment: I had same problem when I forgot to publish datasource. Try republish everything.

Comment: I don't think Glass is resolving, can you make sure all your glass configs are being loaded via showconfig?

Comment: @ASURA That did it. Glass was not installed correctly on my Models project. The site is now working.

Comment: Glad that worked!

Comment: @ASURA Please consider converting your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hetal, I am just going to add it as an answer for potential users to benefit from.

It could be one of the following:

1. Glass not being installed/configured properly (Glass DLL's or
   configs missing or are of previous versions)
2. The Datasource item is not published (mentioned by Marek)

In your case it was Glass not properly installed in the Models project.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After un- and re-installing the newest versions of Glass.Mapper.Sc & Glass.Mapper.Sc.Core package and removing all older versions & configs it worked for me.
Watch out for any custom code or configs not getting lost in the process.